# Ruby 2.2.2 ri documentation

Tags: ruby, ri, ruby-2.2

I'm starting to learn Ruby, so I installed Ruby 2.2.2 via Macports.  I understand that the `ri` documentation does not install by default, so I want to generate it.  I read a few questions/answers on SO and came up with this:

`gem install rdoc-data`

`rdoc-data --install`

and was told: `Your ruby version 2.2.2 is not supported, only 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0.0`

How do I get the `ri` documentation for 2.2.2?  Is there another method?

Comment: i have the same issue on Windows7 and OSX with Ruby 2.2.2 and rdoc-data 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 2.0 or the latest, and you use Ruby Installer for Windows then do the following:

In the command prompt and while you are in the Ruby installation folder, it is sufficient to type **gem install rdoc-data** in the command prompt. This results into generating rdocs in the folder named **doc** in the Ruby installation folder.

Instead of browsing online to check for API or documentations, you can just conveniently open the files in the doc folder. I know it is kind of against the teaching of most books and tutorials for Ruby, but keep it in mind that you just generated an API in your hard-drive and you do not have to use **ri** in the command prompt. You can just have the API open the entire time while coding.